# Composer's dilema - Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am a composer. I have 10, 30-second musical sections. The orchestra plays 5, five are played by a soloist. I would like to give them each choices. I have written the piece so that each section flows well into 2 sections that the others play.

The orchestra "mappings" are 1=>B&D 2=>C&D 3=>C&E 4=>A&B 5=>A&E. The soloist mappings are A=>2&4 B=>2&5 C=>3&4 D=>1&3 E=>1&5

Optional stipulation: The groups can play the same section twice, but must choose an unplayed section when given a choice.

I would like the piece to start with orchestra playing section 1 and end the when the soloist has played all A-E. The problem is, when I write out a flow chart, about 50% of the time there is a section that the soloist has not played after 10 back and forths.   Furthermore, many ways forward never find this last section

So my question is, is there a way to change the mappings (rewrite parts of the piece), so that the soloist will get to play each of their 5 sections.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you're doing, and what you mean by "getting loops". Please edit the question to explain in more detail how your problem works. An example might help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your goal is to redefine your "mappings" so that no matter what choices of transitions the performers make early on, the soloist can always play all five sections-but the orchestra may repeat sections?

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thank you very much for the edits. Currently, both the orchestra and the soloist can play sections more than once. I forgot to add that I am trying to solve the problem by tell both groups, if they come apon a decision, play the section they have not played yet (any thoughts on how I could word this in the question are appreciated). This helps, but only insomuch as it reduces the unplayed section to one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's a graph of the situation, where the good sounding edges are included. It's a pretty graph, if you ask me. I assume this is basically what your flow chart was.
[image]
  and our goal is to find paths, visiting every vertex (at least once). This is a nice visualization of the problem. There are currently exactly two valid paths:

> 1-D-3-E-5-A-4-B-2-C
>   1-D-3-E-5-A-2-C-4-B

These are the only paths that uses each section exactly once. If you want to be sure of that, notice that a cycle can't start 1-B-2, since it would then have to visit D then 3 - at which point it could go to E, but then C would be unreachable, or it could go to C-4-A, but then it would be forced to repeat. It also couldn't start 1-B-5, since then it would either go to E, and be forced to repeat thereafter, or go to A then 2 (since going to 4 would force going to B next), but then we could show that there would be no unused outgoing paths from 4, meaning it would have to end there, which is a problem since if exactly 10 sections were used, it would end with the soloist. This suffices to show that it wouldn't be able to start 1-B without repeat. Similarly, it can't start 1-D-3-C, as that would mean when the orchestra played section 2, it would have to repeat. This suffices to show any such path must start 1-D-3-E-5-A and there are only two paths from there.

There are most certainly more paths when you relax your conditions as you have, and if you think about why certain paths are failing, you can try to move edges about to help it out a little; perhaps avoiding the cycles between two sections would increase the number of good orders to play the music in. This is certainly something you have to play around with more than something you can solve rigorously though, but if you just try to figure out where things go wrong for a lot of paths, you can figure out what you need to change to solve those issues and at least create more paths through the graph.

You could also start with two sets of five points, and start drawing paths of length $10$ through them, alternating between the two sets (soloist & orchestra) - which would possible orders to play the piece - and continually add new such paths until you had every node of the graph with exactly $2$ outgoing edges. If you do this well, it should yield a graph with more potential paths through it - but given that you've already written the piece, I would imagine that entirely changing the structure of the piece is not a great option.

Comment: If I understand correctly he wants some of the sections played more than one, so there are 20 sections rather than 10. If we understand that to mean that each of the 20 "good" transitions should be played exactly once, I count (by exhaustive search!) 96 different Eulerian cycles that can be played -- and each cycle can be started at two different points, giving a total of 192 different possible performances.

Comment: It feels a tad ambitious to expect that the performers can navigate the graph on the fly, but one might assign an extra performer to keep track of where in the possible graph they are and give hand signals (or something) when the choice _now_ is forced by those already taken.

Comment: x @Meelo, if you move nodes 1 and D to the right of the 3E edge, you can get down to one crossing for the graph.

Comment: @Henning It might be that they wish for the greedy algorithm of "choose a section that has not yet been played" to yield a good result, no matter what other choices have been made - but perhaps it's better to wait for the OP to comment, since it seems rather unclear. (And as for performance, I'm pretty sure we're allowed to expect unbounded virtuosity from the soloist and that the conductor will consider not getting lost a priority - so we should be fine as long as those assumptions hold)

Comment: x @Meelo, yes, it is reasonably clear to me that to OP's _hope_ is that such a purely local rule like that would prevent ending up in an unwinnable state. I'm very skeptical that this is actually possible even with changing the shape of the graph (unless it becomes trivial and boring).

Comment: Thank you both for your work! There is no conductor. The performers know the choices they have and must keep track of what they have played. When the soloist has played her last section she moves on to a separate ending. Doing a few sections twice is fine as long as there is an end point. Yes, the goal is that the each section is played regardless of the choices.

Comment: I will try to reduce the cycles by which I understand 1=>d=>1=>d. Perhaps the additional rule of if you come apon the same decision twice, you make the opposite one as the last time.

Btw. I am the composer’s assistant but I have been forwarding these comments to her to get her feedback. We thought my slight background in Math made me the best conduit but apparently I am a layman.

Comment: How about forming a graph that Fleury's method could be applied to? I am not sure if the implementation is feasible but it seems to give choice at least early in the peice.

Comment: @Mike I'd suspect that just trying to make a graph with more circuits is the best heuristic; Fluery's method generates a cycle involving every *transition* between sections - like you'd always get both 1->B and 1->D. It's also not trivial to implement, since you have to keep track of whether an is a "bridge" or not, and I suspect this would be prohibitive to mental calculation. What you're asking is for a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) (allowing repeated vertices), but able to be found by only considering local structures of the graph.

Comment: ... To my knowledge, no suitable algorithm is known, and finding a graph conducive to such an approach is certainly a tricky problem. I would just use the heuristic of "Make a graph with lots of valid paths with no repetition". This *should* make it so that, most of the time, if you just randomly pass through the graph, you'll pass each vertex in a reasonable period of time. (And you can test this on paper - just randomly choose edges to traverse and if you often get stuck in one place doing this, move an edge to go out of that place - 10 vertices is small enough to do it this way)